# Issues looking up Lasted Logged on users and outputting all the information to a CSV

Tags: powershell

The basic thing I am trying to do is take a csv with the columns 'Computer Name','OS', 'Lasted Logged In', 'Users' and look up the users display name and office and export them to a new csv with all of the original information as well as the new. I have been successful getting the information from AD and exporting that information to a separate csv. But I have not found a way to get all the information in one CSV nor put blanks in if the user is not found in AD.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$computers = Import-Csv C:\Temp\inputfile.csv

$computers | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_.Users
    if ($user -ne "N/A" -or $user -ne $null -or $user -ne '')
    {
        Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=$user)" -Property name, office | Select-Object -Property Name, Office
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What I get is an output file with the Display Name and Office for all of the people except the ones that error out but I have no way to tell which Computers they go to as that information is not in the csv.

I have looked at multiple sites for information and I know it is probably a simple fix but Powershell is new for me and I've been researching for the past 6 hours so I"m asking for a little help. Thanks.

Comment: Put a try/catch inside the foreach so that it can process the iteration even though some thing wrong. Thats the way to handle exceptions inside loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like:

```
Import-Csv C:\Temp\inputfile.csv | ForEach-Object {

    if ($_.Users -notin ('N/A', $null, ''))
    {        
        $AdUser = Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(samaccountname=$($_.Users))" -Property Name, Office

        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'DisplayName' -NotePropertyValue $AdUser.Name
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Office'      -NotePropertyValue $AdUser.Office
    }

    $_

} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will merge the display name and office information into each computer record.

Comment: Thank you that worked wonderfully for combining them all in the same file.  I really appreciate the help!